# mongoose group by geo location

Tags: mongodb

So I am wondering if it is possible to group if the geo location long and lat are already recorded.

Basically I am trying to do a heatmap (and well can't work it out in reactjs). So the next option is to group the long and lat if they match and give each a value (0-10) the larger the number the larger the div size.

But now I need to work out how to group this.

```
location.aggregate([
            {  
              $addFields: {
                location: {
                  coordinates: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$location.coordinates",
                      in: { $toString: "$$this" }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
                $group: {"$location.coordinates"}
            },
            {
                $unset:["traits","UUID","createdAt","updatedAt"]
            },
            {$skip:0},
            { $limit: 600 }
          ])
```

RAW JSON

```
{"_id":"5ef6f03e5b43e19dabf7c705","__v":0,"location":{"coordinates":["115.862","-31.9674"]}},{"_id":"5ef6f0d55b43e19dabf7d8a1","__v":0,"location":{"coordinates":["115.862","-31.9674"]}},{"_id":"5ef6f1355b43e19dabf7e32d","__v":0,"location":{"coordinates":["115.862","-31.9674"]}},{"_id":"5ef6f2915b43e19dabf80a39","__v":0,"location":{"coordinates":["115.862","-31.9674"]}},{"_id":"5ef6f4055b43e19dabf83819","__v":0,"location":{"coordinates":["115.862","-31.9674"]}},{"_id":"5ef6f5d95b43e19dabf86d13","__v":0,"location":{"coordinates":["115.862","-31.9674"]}},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by `location.coordinates`
- `$project` to convert decimal coordinates to string in `location.coordinates` field

```
location.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$location.coordinates" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "location.coordinates": {
        $map: {
          input: "$_id",
          in: { $toString: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $skip: 0 },
  { $limit: 600 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o0_Tfvxbv9C)

Comment: That worked - anyway to get it to addField of how many got grouped? - and thank you so very much

Comment: added count when group, check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aEU1nJ1jQij)